# Why footer doesn't appear correctly in Internet Explorer 8 and 11?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, dom, position, absolute

In code tags Main and Footer are placed in the same level.

```html
 <main class="Full">
  <div class="Sleeve">
   <div class="Columns">
     <div class="LeftCol">  </div>
  <div class="RightCol">   </div>
    </div>
   </div> 
  </main>
  <footer class="Full">
     <div class="Sleeve">
    <div class="FooterData"> 2014 - 2015<div id="mymap"></div></div>
     </div>
  </footer>
```

But IE11 removes Footer into Main, after div.RightCol. I don't unterstand why IE redesign DOM so strange?
p.s. I want footer is always placed in bottom of page, therefore for Footer in css I specify  Position:absolute. Maybe it is the reason of trouble? Or the reason that IE can't define tags Footer and Main (Doctype - html5)?

---

Footer is after closing main tag.

---

Thank you very much! This is exactly what I need.

---

UPD: indeed, in IE11 all was OK, I made mistake in html code. I'm sorry for misleading question.

Comment: Because `footer` is an html5 tag. See [caniuse html5 semantic](http://caniuse.com/#feat=html5semantic) on caniuse website. That only explains your problem relative to IE8 of course.

Comment: Thank you for this site! So, my problems in IE11  are due to the fact that all versions IE doesn't support Main?

Comment: As for IE11 the problem must be elsewhere, but without the CSS that would be hard to guess. Can you post your CSS styles?

Comment: And is there any lifehack except change tags?

Comment: main{
min-height:100%;
padding:0 0 30px;
position:relative;
top:-15px;
}

Comment: footer{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
height:60px;
background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #22180c, #33291d 50%, #22180c 100%);
background:#22180b;
margin:10px 0 0 !important;
}

Comment: You can edit the question and add the styles to the question, that would be better. Yes, there are solutions for enabling html5 tags for IE8, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Is your dom at least correct in IE11, I mean is the footer after the closing main tag?

Answer (score 1):

The tags `main` and `footer` come from the HTML5 semantic. In Internet Explorer, HTML5 tags are supported starting from version 9. See [caniuse website](http://caniuse.com/#feat=html5semantic)

Because IE8 does not recognize these tags, your DOM is messed. However, there is a solution if you want to 'enable' these tags in IE8.

You will have to import in your project a library called [html5shiv](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv). Then, in the `<head>` of your page, add the following :

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="path/to/html5shiv/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

This is a conditional comment meaning the following :

*if the browser is **lt IE9** (= less than IE9), load the script html5shiv*

If loaded, the script will create missing elements as :

```
article 
aside 
figcaption 
figure 
footer 
header 
main 
nav 
section
```

and a few others.